# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Tomcat 8.5 for RESTful web app

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, classnotfoundexception

Im trying to create a RESTful web app and Im running into a Error 500 I've looked around at some answers and tried out the solutions with no avail.

Java Serverlet code

```
package org.some.package.tohere;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/somepath")
public class Analysis {
    @POST
    public String ClassName(@FormParam("inputArray[]") List<String> datalist) {
        // Results results=Send to other
        // ResultstoFirebase
        return "Woooooo";

    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


  <display-name>Project Name</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>test.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Name</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.some.package.tohere;</param-value>
  </init-param>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ProjectName</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/analysis/* </url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Javascript

```
function callGeneSpotService(inputArray)
{

    var location =window.location.href+"analysis/somepath"
    //Results should be the encrypted job id to be able to access the results on the web page.
    var results = $.post(location,{inputArray:inputArray},function(response){
    })
    .done(function(results)
  {
    alert(results);
    //alert("Now Processing, please check back in the results section with your job id in a few moments: "+ results);
  })
  .fail(function(results)
  {
    alert("Something went wrong please contact the systems administrator for help");
  })

}
```

Error Stack

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class >com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Not sure what else would help answer the question but I would be happy to provide

Comment: Do you have `jersey` in your classpath?

Comment: jersey-bundle-1.19.3.jar correct? Yes I do.

Comment: Does `ClassNotFoundException: >com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` mean anything to you?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes and no, for me at least it makes it seem I have a dependency missing or some connection to ServletContainer is missing. However what that connection is I am not sure in this context

Comment: Its also part of my web.xml

Comment: aaannd there was an extra arrow in the web.xml

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking at this, the answers above are good for the same question but my issue was I had an extra '>' like a dingus in my web.xml